# Moving jQuery to footer from header

Tags: jquery, troubleshooting

Here is my file. My wordpress is 4.5

```
===============================
    FRONT-END ENQUEUE FUNCTIONS
===============================
*/
function sunset_load_scripts(){

wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '3.3.7', 'all' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'sunset', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/sunset.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all' );

wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
wp_register_script( 'jquery' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js', false, '1.11.3', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.7', true );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sunset_load_scripts' );
```

Comment: what is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) is :

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js', array(), '1.11.3', true);
```

The last parameter is $in_footer set it true which will insert the script into the footer.

**Note:** [You don't need to include jquery bcz by default it is added in WordPress](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#notes).